# Windows Phone ListViewItem stretch to the width of ListView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, datatemplate, windows-10-mobile

I have created one `ListView`. In this `ListView` I am binding **custom** `DataTemplate`. SO I am binding this `custom DataTemplate` to **ListView**.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="myAlerts" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <userControls:CustomDataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                <userControls:CustomDataTemplateSelector.FriendRequest>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Background="Transparent" >
                            <Grid>
                                //Binding som element here
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </userControls:CustomDataTemplateSelector.FriendRequest>
            </userControls:CustomDataTemplateSelector>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here issue is, my all **Items** in `DataTemplate` is not **Horizontalically stretching**. Can anyone know how to **Stretch** custom Template items?

Comment: Use DataTemplateSelector instead of UserControl. See example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I used same. `DataTemplateSelector` is in my `usercontrol` folder

Comment: You should assign it to  <ListView.ItemTemplateSelector> property instead of "ItemTemplate"

Comment: @RavingDev Thanks for reply I will try this.

Comment: @RavingDev I tried same solution http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector

Comment: @RavingDev My is solved. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved. I set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to my custom DataTemplate.

```
<userControls:CustomDataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <userControls:CustomDataTemplateSelector.FriendRequest>
        <DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate>
    <userControls:CustomDataTemplateSelector.FriendRequest>
</userControls:CustomDataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```